# Naval fiction novel about two officers arguing over who has rank after the senior crew are killed by enemy fire

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to recall the name of a (1950s?) WW2 naval fiction novel that I read, possibly Herman Wouk or similar.

A small military ship, probably in the Corvette class suffers a catastrophic attack from some German blighters and the senior officers are killed. The two remaining, similarly lowly-ranked officers have a protracted argument over which of them has seniority (and hence to take over the ship) and eventually resolve the matter by disclosing their '*naval list number*(?)'.

One of them signed up for naval service a few days earlier than the other and hence has a higher (possibly lower?) number and is therefore *very technically* the more senior, which the other concedes with ill grace.

I'm trying to remember the outcome of this brilliant stroke, but I believe the now-captain immediately orders the other crew, including his fellow, to abandon ship and yet remains on board himself to try to drop a few last shells onto the German ship as it approaches to finish them off. I forget if he was killed in the process, but it always struck me as quite a courageous set of actions, given that nobody would have blamed him for scuttling an already-doomed ship and making for shore.

Comment: I wonder whether this plot point was inspired by Chard and Bromhead at Rourke's Drift? (Although there the difference was three years, not a few days)

Comment: I know you specify this was a novel -- could it have been a short story? Which war was it set during?

Comment: @tgdavies - World War II, I think a relatively short novel rather than a short story.

Comment: @tgdavies - Possibly inspired by. I remember that the closing point of their argument was that one of their list numbers was marginally higher. The one claimed that this wasn't a fair measure but the other insisted that this was correct *under the strictest interpretation of military policy, even if it was a matter of days or even hours*. Note that both wanted the command because they intended to go down with the ship (and save the other), not because they wanted the glory

Comment: I can imagine C S Forester writing this in his patriotic WW2 phase -- but it would be a short story, definitely not a novel, and I think I'd remember it.